# Dynamic Route name Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want to create dynamic route name for my app. Here is my route file

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{team}/dashboard', 'middleware' => 'isMember'], function() {

Route::get('/user', array('uses' => 'UserController@index', 'as' => 'user.index'));
Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@edit', 'as' => 'user.edit'));
Route::patch('/user/{id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@update', 'as' => 'user.update'));
Route::delete('/user/{id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@destroy', 'as' => 'user.delete'));
```

it's not simple if i have to define route like this

```
'route' => ['user.delete', $team,  $user->id]
```

or

```
public function destroy($team,$id) {
   // do something
    return redirect()->route('user.index', $team);
}
```

I want to generate route name like "$myteam.user.delete" or something more simplier like when i define "user.delete" it includes my team name.

How i can do that? is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by setting **as**. Also using resource routes will be handy.

```
$routeName = 'team.';

Route::group(['as' => $routeName], function(){
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
});
```

Now you can call like

```
route('team.user.index');
```

More on resource routes here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Route::delete('/user/{team}/{id}', array('uses' => 'UserController@deleteTeamMember', 'as' => 'myteam.user.delete'));
```

Now call the route as:

```
route('myteam.user.delete', [$team, $id]);
```

Comment: i think it's like my previous code. as a note : myteam is a variable from prefix.